# Python test Average Calculator returen error 'list' object has no attribute 'len'

Tags: python

Hey this is a demo to show some of my classmates an intro to python and coding. The code below should be able to take a list like `[0,1]` and if run using the `average` function would return 0.5. When run using a list the function below returns the error `'list' object has no attribute 'len'`. How would I get this function to work without removing the `len()` function

```
def average(lst):
    total = 0
    for item in lst:
        total += item
    averageGrade= total / lst.len()
    return averageGrade
```

How would I also get it to return a float rather than an integer

Comment: If you want to get the length of a collection as a method of this collection, you can use `lst.__len__()`.
It sometimes comes handy if you want to chain operators.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Change the line

```
averageGrade= total / lst.len()
```

to

```
averageGrade= total / len(lst)
```

Refer the python docs for the built-in [len](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len). The built-in len calculates the number of items in a sequence. As list is a sequence, the built-in can work on it.

The reason it fails with the error `'list' object has no attribute 'len'`, because, `list` data type does not have any method named `len`. Refer the python docs for [list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Another important aspect is you are doing an integer division. In Python 2.7 (which I assume from your comments), unlike Python 3, returns an integer if both operands are integer.

Change the line

```
total = 0.0
```

to convert one of your operand of the divisor to float.

Comment: You should mention integer division!

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Yes, I did not notice it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4):

or by changing

```
averageGrade= total / lst.len()
```

to:

```
averageGrade= total / lst.__len__()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just** **change** `lst.len()`  **to** `len(list)`

> Also can refer [Progamiz Python - len](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/len) for more information